# What is the purpose of the esc key in a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

Open a terminal press the esc key then press a number followed by a letter. The result is the letter repeated number of times

Example:
`esc 3 t`

the result is:
`ttt`

Is there a use case for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a feature of the terminal, it's a feature of some applications running in the terminal, including common shells such as bash and zsh.

<kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by a number is a *prefix argument*. This feature comes from Emacs. Every Emacs command can use the prefix argument to influence its behavior. The convention is that for commands where it makes sense, the prefix argument is a repeat count. For example,  <kbd>Escape</kbd>  <kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Right</kbd> moves 42 characters to the right. Negative arguments indicate "opposite" behavior where it makes sense, for example   <kbd>Escape</kbd>  <kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Right</kbd> moves 2 characters to the left. Similarly,  <kbd>Escape</kbd>  <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> inserts `t` 3 times.

Comment: Sounds like it's in Emacs straight out of Vi actually (`Esc` to get into normal mode, then a repeat count and a command).

Comment: @Kusalananda Prefixing a command with a numeric argument is older than both Emacs and vi and I doubt that they influenced each other on this. It was present in both ed and TECO. Using ESC as a “prefix” is a coincidence: in vi it's to exit insert mode, in Emacs it's a substitute for the Meta modifier. Also, in Emacs, the “main” prefix argument command is `C-u`, and ESC also works mainly so you can use Meta+digit, but shells tend to preserve the terminal meaning of `C-u` to clear the line.

Comment: Given the lineage from `ed` into `vi`, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' `ed` does not have a repeat-next-command-this-many-times facility as far as I know, but I get your point that what I thought was a transfer of functionality from `vi` to `emacs` might have been a coincident.

Comment: @Kusalananda Emacs and vi are contemporaneous (1976)! Both derive from older editors: ed for vi and TECO for Emacs. Ed already had numbers before commands to indicate a line number; I guess that changing this to “move by N” for relative motion was a natural transposition. If there was any influence between the two, it would have been from TECO to vi, since TECO had that in the 1960s. According to [“The Beginnings of TECO” by Dan Murphy](https://opost.com/tenex/anhc-31-4-anec.pdf), TECO got that from the DDT debugger at DEC.

Comment: Thank you this really helped understand the use case.

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful on a terminal with key repeat disabled.
Edit: I guess that doesn't really answer your question. I could see it being used to double a letter in a command such as hello, which has 2 l's.

Comment: ...except of course that `ESC 2 l` has three keystrikes, instead of just two for `ll`, and on modern keyboards, requires moving a hand far off from the letter area to reach the faraway ESC.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a specific instance of the behaviour with Esc. It does not replicate keystrokes as such.

From Bash Manual: "If you do not have a Meta or ALT key, or another key working as a Meta key, the identical keystroke can be generated by typing ESC first, and then typing k. Either process is known as metafying the k key."

What happens then at the command line is that you get dropped into the `readline` editor. Depending on the current `set -o`, you might then be in vi mode or emacs mode, or in readline's own edit commands.

Shells other than Bash will have their own variations. It is not terminal behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, and what is happening when the esc is pressed.